# parsing the nested json in swift

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I am new to swift. Here is a deserialized JSON

```
Optional({
    data =     (
                {
            comments =             (
                                {
                    comments = good;
                    "created_date" = "2018-01-01";
                    id = 2;
                    likes = 0;
                    "news_id" = 4;
                    status = 1;
                    "user_id" = 5;
                }
            );
            date = 1510167600000;
            id = 4;
            images = "0c980d3f9cd0393a46bb04995d16177a.jpg";
            likes = 25;
            title = facebook;
            totalcoments = 1;
        },
                {
            comments =             (
                                {
                    comments = "Good News";
                    "created_date" = "2018-01-01";
                    id = 1;
                    likes = 2;
                    "news_id" = 7;
                    status = 1;
                    "user_id" = 5;
                },
                                {
                    comments = "well good";
                    "created_date" = "2018-01-02";
                    id = 3;
                    likes = 0;
                    "news_id" = 7;
                    status = 1;
                    "user_id" = 5;
                },
                                {
                    comments = "well good";
                    "created_date" = "2018-01-02";
                    id = 4;
                    likes = 0;
                    "news_id" = 7;
                    status = 1;
                    "user_id" = 5;
                },
                                {
                    comments = "well good";
                    "created_date" = "2018-01-03";
                    id = 5;
                    likes = 0;
                    "news_id" = 7;
                    status = 1;
                    "user_id" = 5;
                }
            );
            date = 1511377200000;
            id = 7;
            images = "0c980d3f9cd0393a46bb04995d16177a.jpg";
            likes = 3;
            title = don;
            totalcoments = 4;
        },
                {
            comments =             (
            );
            date = 1510513200000;
            id = 8;
            images = "0c980d3f9cd0393a46bb04995d16177a.jpg";
            likes = 90;
            title = Dell;
            totalcoments = 0;
        },
                {
            comments =             (
            );
            date = 1515351600000;
            id = 14;
            images = "0c980d3f9cd0393a46bb04995d16177a.jpg";
            likes = 0;
            title = dfsfdsfdfs;
            totalcoments = 0;
        }
    );
    message = "Success.";
    newsurl = "http://dev.nsol.sg/projects/sneakers/assets/brand_images/thumb/";
    success = 1;
    totalnews = 4;
})
```

Here in following class i am trying to parse the json

```
   import UIKit

class getData: NSObject {

    var descriptionn : String = ""
    var image : String = ""
    var likes : String = ""
    var comments : Int = 0
    var com:String=""
    var like:String = ""

    func getDataForTableView(results: [[String:Any]], index : Int){

        var productArray = [String:Any]()
        productArray = results[index]

        descriptionn = productArray["title"]! as! String
        image = productArray["images"]! as! String
        likes=productArray["likes"]! as! String
        comments=productArray["totalcoments"]! as! Int
        /*{
            comments =             (
                {
                    comments = good;
                    "created_date" = "2018-01-01";
                    id = 2;
                    likes = 0;
                    "news_id" = 4;
                    status = 1;
                    "user_id" = 5;
                }
            );*/
        //code for parsing the "comments" section of json is 
      let comment=productArray["comments"] as! [String:Any]?
        com = comment!["comments"] as! String
        like = comment!["likes"] as! String



    }
}
```

The code for populating the table view cell is below

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "discoveryNewscell") as! DiscoveryNewsTableViewCell


           classObject.getDataForTableView(results: results, index: indexPath.row)
cell.sneakerImageView.image=filteredsneakernews[indexPath.row].image
            cell.newsTitle.text = classObject.descriptionn
            cell.likes.text=classObject.likes
            cell.comments.text=String(classObject.comments)
            let imageURLPathString = newsurl + classObject.image
            print("comments")
            print(classObject.image)
            let url1 = URL(string: imageURLPathString)
            print("xyz", url1)
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url1!)

            if let imageData = data {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                cell.sneakerImageView.image = image
            }

            return cell


        }
```

Here is didSelectRowAt Index path function

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let storybaord=UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabBar=storybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! UITabBarController

        let DVC = tabBar.viewControllers?[0] as! NewsViewController
        classObject.getDataForTableView(results: results, index: indexPath.row)


        let imageURLPathString = newsurl + classObject.image

        let url1 = URL(string: imageURLPathString)
        print("xyz", url1)
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url1!)

        if let imageData = data {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            DVC.getImage = image!
        }

        let news = classObject.descriptionn
        DVC.getNews = news
        DVC.getnumberOfComment=classObject.comments
        print("comment")
//code for passing "comment" part of json to view controller
        print(classObject.like)
        print(classObject.com)
        DVC.getlikes=classObject.like
        DVC.getcomment=classObject.com

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBar, animated: true)
    }
```

I want when a particular row is selected from table view it should display the number of "likes" and "comments" that are from nested part of JSON on "Likes Screen" view controller

```
comments =             (
                                    {
                        comments = good;
                        "created_date" = "2018-01-01";
                        id = 2;
                        likes = 0;
                        "news_id" = 4;
                        status = 1;
                        "user_id" = 5;
                    }
                );
```

How to read and parse that nested "Comments" in JSON? You can download the project from this link .https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VYM4nywaBYDP2BcyBYPPNUYAu_18mhd9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please read the deserialized JSON: There are only two different collection types. `()` is array, `{}` is dictionary so you can see that the object for key `comments` is clearly an **array** (`[[String:Any]]`). It's highly recommended to use the `Codable` protocol in Swift 4 to deserialize the JSON directly into structs.

Comment: Now i am parsing comments as :                                                        let comment=productArray["comments"] as! [[String:Any]]?
        ....these two statement are giving error .....                                       
        com = comment!["comments"] as! String .                                                                            
        like = comment!["likes"] as! String